# Alternatives of JavaScript Proxy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, observer-pattern, es6-proxy

I want to use `Proxy` on a customized class called `ObservableList` which contains an `Array`. Since `Proxy` is available only after ES6, I wonder if there is any alternative implementation.

My requirement is to get updated (rather than get noticed) for observers once `ObservableList` changes, so that the observers are always consist with observable with some filtering or mapping method.

```
var activities = new ObservableList(['reading', 'swimming']);
var sAct = activities.filter(function(v) {
  return v[0] === 's';
});
// expect sAct.list to be ['swimming']
var meAct = activities.map(function(v) {
  return 'I am ' + v;
});
// expect meAct.list to be ['I am reading', 'I am swimming']

activities.list.push('smiling');
console.log(sAct.list, meAct.list);
// expect sAct.list to be ['swimming', 'smiling']
// expect meAct.list to be ['I am reading', 'I am swimming', 'I am smiling']

activities.list[1] = 'snoopying';
console.log(sAct.list, meAct.list);
// expect sAct.list to be ['swimming', 'snoopying']
// expect meAct.list to be ['I am reading', 'I am snoopying', 'I am smiling']
```

My implementation with Proxy is available at https://jsfiddle.net/ovilia/tLmbptr0/3/

Comment: Is it `activities.push` or `activities.list.push`?

Comment: What usage scenarios does your observable list need to work in? So far you've only shown calling a `push` method and assigning to already-existing indices. What else do you need? Please be specific.

Comment: @Bergi `activities.list.push`. I need all array operations like `push`, `shift`, `splice` and etc. to be watched.

Comment: If that is all, you don't even need proxies - just subclass `Array` and overwrite every update method with one that calls super and then notifies the observers.

Comment: @Bergi Array indexers and `length` are hard to patch with this approach. @LiuJi-Jim's answer is widely adopted in many frameworks. It's frustrating, but somehow works. Or dirty check, like Angular, boring and ugly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in questions, I only need `ObservableList` to *contain* an `Array`, rather than to *extend* it, as Jim did in his *complicated* answer. And surprisingly enough, I found this could be easily achieved **by wrapping the original `Array` operations**.

One limitation is that **index operation is not reactive** in my implementation, in that I failed to find a proper way to capture index operations. If you have a better idea, feel welcomed to tell me! XD

Here's the full implementation.

```
export class ObservableList {

  list: Array<any>;

  private _observer: Array<ObserverList>;

  constructor(list?: Array<any>) {
    this.list = list || [];
    this._initList();
    this._initMethods();

    this._observer = [];
  }

  notify(): void {
    for (let o of this._observer) {
      o.update();
    }
  }

  private _initList(): void {
    var that = this;
    var operations = ['push', 'pop', 'shift', 'unshift', 'splice',
      'sort', 'reverse'];
    for (let operation of operations) {
      this.list[operation] = function() {
        var res = Array.prototype[operation].apply(that.list, arguments);
        that.notify();
        return res;
      }
    }
  }

  private _initMethods(): void {
    var that = this;
    var methods = ['filter', 'map'];
    for (let method of methods) {
      this[method] = (formatter: Function): ObserverList => {
        var observer = new ObserverList(that, formatter, method);
        this._observer.push(observer);
        return observer;
      }
    }
  }

}

export class ObserverList {

  public list: Array<any>;

  constructor(public observable: ObservableList, 
              public formatter: Function, 
              public method: string) {
    this.list = [];
    this.update();
  }

  update(): void {
    var list = [];
    var master = this.observable.list;
    for (var i = 0, len = master.length; i < len; ++i) {
      if (this.method === 'filter') {
        if (this.formatter(master[i])) {
          list.push(master[i]);
        }
      } else if (this.method === 'map') {
        list.push(this.formatter(master[i]));
      } else {
        console.error('Illegal method ' + this.method + '.');
      }
    }
    this.list = list;
  }

}
```

Comment: Wait a minute, this is TypeScript, isn't it?

Comment: @Leo Yes, but I don't think it makes any difference, right?

Answer (score 2):

used `defineProperty`.

not exactly with what you want. i just implemented a "reactive array". but i think it maybe works in your problems.

bad parts:

1. defined tons of getters/setters on the target.
2. accessing indexers not defined will be not reactive.
3. `update()` is to-be optimized.

good parts:

1. ES5 friendly.
2. if no indexers needed, use `set(i, val)/get(i)` will be reactive.

https://jsfiddle.net/jimnox/jrtq40p7/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is using proxies a hard requirement? I wouldn't recommend proxies for
general programming tasks as you can end up with unpredictable and
hard-to-spot side effects.

If you keep to data and functions to transform it, avoiding mutable
state where possible, I think you'll end up with simpler code that's
easier to maintain.

```js
var activities = ['reading', 'swimming'];

var sfilter = function(activities){
    return activities.filter(function(v){
        return v[0] === 's';
    });
};

console.log(sfilter(activities));

var memap = function(activities){
    return activities.map(function(v){
        return 'I am ' + v;
    });
};

console.log(memap(activities));

activities.push('smiling');
console.log(sfilter(activities));
console.log(memap(activities));

// Yes, I know this doesn't work in quite the same way,
// but you're asking for trouble here since in your
// code you're appending to one list, but overwriting
// an element in the other.
activities[1] = 'snoopying';
console.log(sfilter(activities));
console.log(memap(activities));
```

Stick to a Single Source of Truth and observe that. With each copy you are multiplying state complexity. That will make debugging, testing, and extending the code difficult.

Comment: This is way off tracking. The OP intends to achieve a **reactive** programming paradigm that is also compatible with ES5. That's why he/she wants to get rid of `Proxy`, which is the perfect use case (but only available after ES6). IMO this wouldn't and shouldn't be some business logic. It's more like a framework level requirement.

Comment: @Leo sure. I was  remarking on the OP's idea of updating mirrored data rather than observing; I didn't make that clear.